# How to capture multiple images within one sec in android camera?

Tags: android, android-camera

Right now, i am working on capturing multiple images within one sec. Once the camera has been opened it should take four images within one sec or lessthen one sec but my code takes more than one sec for 4 images lets say its take 4 or 5 secs for process. I reffered many codes but still can't get a solution, it will be much helpfull if anyone gives some idea or a solution to this problem. For example like Brust mode app in android camera.

Below is my code:

```
                    case 1:
                    camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureCallback);
                    captureCount++;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureCallback);
                    captureCount++;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureCallback);
                    captureCount++;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureCallback);
                    captureCount++;
                    break;
```

Comment: For Android prior to 5.x.x many seem to suggest using preview frames is the only way to capture burst images. Starting from 5.x.x the new Camera2 API allows burst capturing.

Comment: @harism can you show me any link or examples for burst capturing using preview frames.

Comment: question is what takes 4-5 sec? it is a time between camera.takePicture call and begin of pictureCallback.onPictureTaken  or end of pictureCallback.onPictureTaken

Answer (score 0):

1、set small picture size;

```
List<Camera.Size> list = param.getSupportedPictureSizes();
size = list.get(list.size() - 1);//or list.size() - 2,-3,-4
param.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);
```

2、do every

```
camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureCallback);
```

in a thread.

```
new Thread(){};
```

Comment: @Selvin But the source code of android 4.0 camera,when taking a picture,code also uses a thread to do that.But yes ,it's asynchronous in camera2 API.

Comment: @Selvin Sorry,after answering the question,I read the camera code in freamwork,when takePicture() invoked,it's true that this method is asynchronous..So,I want to say that, if you want to save pictures to  SD card,you should do that in thread (the callback, "pictureCallback").

Answer (score 0):

```
            case 1:
                camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureCallback);
                captureCount++;

            case 2:
                camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureCallback);
                captureCount++;

            case 3:
                camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureCallback);
                captureCount++;

            case 4:
                camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureCallback);
                captureCount++;
```

try above code ... i think now it will work ... coz breaking of switch takes some fraction of seconds if still this will not work then try to make use of while / for loop & the final solution will be making use of threading concept in java

Comment: so simply this code become `camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureCallback);camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureCallback);camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureCallback);camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureCallback);` but written in sensless way ...

Comment: i told you to just try otherwise make use of threading concept that will perfect for you

Comment: camera.takePicture is asynchronous ... so, you wana use another thread inside already non ui thread ... even more sensless